# How do I create dynamic user credentials and then use them in later REST requests in soapui pro?

Tags: json, api, rest, soapui

I'm very new to backend testing and all scripting in general, but this is something I was easily able to do on frontend tests using selenium IDE. Basically, in my automation I would like to create a new dynamic username/email and password everytime the automation is ran, and use those credentials in all further tests of the suite.

I have a created a credentials test step with the username and password set up as such:

username: testemail{Math.round (Math.random() * 100000)}@example.com
password: woof{Math.round (Math.random() * 100000)}

In the Registration API REST request, I have entered the following json

{

```
"email": "${Credentials#Username}" ,

"password": "${Credentials#Password}" ,

"country": "us" ,

"firstname": "John" ,

"lastname": "Smith" ,

"lang": "C"
```

}

But it appears it as coming through as such:

{

```
"email": "testemail{Math.round (Math.random() * 100000)}@example.com" ,

"password": "woof{Math.round (Math.random() * 100000)}" ,

"country": "us" ,

"firstname": "John" ,

"lastname": "Smith" ,

"lang": "C"
```

}

What am I doing wrong? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Random values generation and setting properties should be done in groovy script test step. In groovy script write smth like this:

```
import java.util.Random

//generating random values
Random rand = new Random()
String username = "testmail" + rand.nextInt(100000) + "@example.com"
String password = "woof" + rand.nextInt(100000)

//setting test case properties
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("username", username);
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("password", password);
```

In test case you can access this properties as ${#testcase_name#property_name}.

More information about properties here: 
http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#1-accessing-properties-settings-and-names

and about scripting here: 
http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/scripting-and-the-script-library.html